# Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to convert this couple of lines of C# to Vb for hours and i can't make it work.

```vb
Friend Shared Function GetErrorCorrectPolynomial(ByVal errorCorrectLength As Integer) As tPolynomial
    Dim a As tPolynomial

    a =  New tPolynomial(New DataCache() With {1}, 0)

    For i As Integer = 0 To errorCorrectLength - 1
        a = a.Multiply(New tPolynomial(New DataCache() With { 1, tMath.GExp(i) }, 0))
    Next i

    Return a
End Function
```

i get this error 
Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'

in this part {1}

The original code

```csharp
internal static tPolynomial GetErrorCorrectPolynomial(int errorCorrectLength)
{
    tPolynomial a = new tPolynomial(new DataCache() { 1 }, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < errorCorrectLength; i++)
    {
        a = a.Multiply(new tPolynomial(new DataCache() { 1, tMath.GExp(i) }, 0));
    }

    return a;
}
```

Edited to add the Datacache class

```
Friend Class DataCache
    Inherits List(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New(ByVal capacity As Integer)
        MyBase.New()
        For i As Integer = 0 To capacity - 1
            MyBase.Add(0)
        Next i
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx). Use the `From` keyword, like this:

```
New DataCache() From { 1, tMath.GExp(i) }
```

Comment: +1 I believe this answer is correct (should be accepted). This feature was added in Visual Studio 2010 (VB.NET 10). I've never seen it before - interesting! (Though not particularly useful as, in most cases, collections have a class initializer which accepts a source collection)

Comment: Thank you All. Special thanks to Adam who solved my problem. thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the C# you are using, but the VB `With` keyword is used to set properties of the initialized object.

```vb
New Foo() With { .Bar = 1 }
```

where Foo is the class and Bar is the property.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx

This is identical to the way that C# initializes object properties, except C# dispenses with the "`.`"

```csharp
new Foo() { Bar = 1 }
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Cyborg, if you can't understand the C# code you can not imagine my infinite ignorance about that code... please bear with me. i just got this task with no option to reject. All i know is that to finish  it just need to make that procedure works, and i have no clue to solve it. Thanks again for your kind help. (Please see above my edited question where i added the Datacache class)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an implicit conversion between DataCache and Int32 (int/Integer), in which case you should just remove the With keyword:

```
a = New tPolynomial(New DataCache() {1}, 0)
```

Comment: Rolf, thanks a lot for your help. In fact datacache is a class inherited from List(Of Integer).